# Как пронумеровать ячейки таблицы

Tags: php, html

Мне нужно пронумеровать ячейки в таблице html по строкам. То есть сверху-вниз, а когда строки заканчиваются, нужно сдвинуть нумерацию на столбец вправо и продолжить. Можно реализовать такое как-то? С помощью css или php например.
таблица 4х4

нумерация должна выглядеть как то так

```
1 5 9  13
2 6 10 14
3 7 11 15
4 8 12 16
```

Comment: и где ваш код генерации таблицы? первый столбец вроде не должно быть проблемой пронумеровать? а если строк R штук, то и второй пронумеровать не сложно - к значению в первом прибавить R. А в третьем 2*R

Answer (score 2):

```
$rows = 4; // 3
$cols = 4; // 14
echo '<table>';
for($i=1; $i <= $rows; $i++){
    echo '<tr>';
    $n = $i;
    for($j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++){
        echo '<td>'. $n .'</td>';
        $n = $n + $rows;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$n = $n + $rows` => `$j*$rows + $i`

Answer (score 0):

Дк никаких проблем...
Вот, например значения на `php` таблицу уж сами сгенерируйте

```
$rows = 4;
$cols = 4;
$arr = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
  $arr[$i] = [];
  for ($j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++) {
     $arr[$i][$j] = $i+1+$rows*$j;
  }
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: зачем делать цикл с 0, если нумерация с 1, а потом дописывать эту единицу?

Comment: Это называется привычка. И во всех стандартных случаях циклы начинаются с 0. И на результат никак не влияет